# Connecting Microsoft's WebAPI OData service via lightning connect

Tags: lightning-connect

Has anyone tried connecting a Microsoft OData service via External Data Source (Lightning Connect).

I'm trying to achieve this (my OData service is deployed on top of MS WebAPI infrastructure), and when I try to validate & sync the External Data Source, I get this status:

**The external data source isn't using the specified version 2.0.**

Comment: I think everything posted here was true at the time, but there is now new type of connector that probably wasn't available originally `Salesforce Connect: OData 4.0`.  I've currently got my Web API OData controllers on version 4 of OData and am able to have data read successfully via the `External Data Source`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After getting Mohithes answer, I've looked by myself the appropriate way to make the WebAPI  service to use Odata v2 and found [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.http.odata.builder.odatamodelbuilder.dataserviceversion(v=vs.118).aspx):
you're setting the version in the Register method of your WebAPIConfig file:

> ODataConventionModelBuilder builder = new ODataConventionModelBuilder();
>   **builder.DataServiceVersion = new Version("2.0");**
>   builder.EntitySet("myTable");
>   builder.EntitySet("myTable2");
>   ...
>   config.Routes.MapODataServiceRoute("odata", "odata", builder.GetEdmModel());

that solved my problem.

Comment: brilliant .Thanks for sharing some code on this forum

Answer (score 1):

Lightning Connect currently supports only Odata V 2.0 . 3.0 and above and not supported and hence the error .Also the data feed has to be an ATOM feed .

I tried using Windows azure platfom and deployed my webservice there and was able to successfully connect and get SQL data

Here is the blogpost from me on this

http://cloudyworlds.blogspot.in/2015/01/lightning-connect-and-sql-integration.html

http://cloudyworlds.blogspot.in/2015/01/lightning-connect-and-sql-integration_3.html

You may need to lower the Odata version to 2 to get it working .

Comment: Thank you, I'll try to publish an OData version 2 service